# Excel Dynamic lookup in every tab

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking for a function to dynamic perform a lookup in every sheet of my workbook.
Eventually the names of the sheets can be put in a separate sheet, to use the indirect function. I want to know in which sheets a specific value is referenced.

As a sample; I want to know in which sheet names 'Water' (A1) is referenced, comma separated.
If multiple references in the same sheet, the name of the sheet should be listed multiple times.

Doing this static I'm using the following function:

```
=HLOOKUP(A1; Sheet1!A1:A30;1;TRUE)&","&HLOOKUP(A1; Sheet2!A1:A30;1;TRUE)&","&HLOOKUP(A1; Sheet3!A1:A30;1;TRUE)   ....
```

Where on A1 of every sheet I've put the sheet name.

Attached screenshots should make it a bit more clear:

Column A has the values to lookup in every sheet. Column B is what I want to have a dynamic function for:

[image: Result tab]

Sample of a sheet to lookup the value:

[image: Content of one of the tabs]

Do you think this is possible without VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be querying only about 30 rows per sheet, you should be within the limits for a solution using `TEXTJOIN` and `FILTERXML` (larger ranges would make this unfeasible).

Assuming you create an ordered, **vertical** list of your sheet names (e.g. "Joe", "David", "Laura") within a worksheet somewhere - with the leftmost and rightmost sheets at the top and bottom respectively - and store that list as the Defined Name *SheetList*:

`=LET(δ,SheetList,κ,Joe:Laura!A$1:A$30,ζ,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("ξ</b><b>",0,κ)&"ξ</b></a>","//b"),λ,ROWS(ζ),IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",,INDEX(δ,1+QUOTIENT(FILTER(SEQUENCE(λ),ζ=A2&"ξ")-1,λ/ROWS(δ)))),""))`

where the 3D reference

`Joe:Laura!A$1:A$30`

should comprise only the leftmost and rightmost sheets of those to be queried.